# Cucumber scenario is not joined with the steps code

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, cucumber-java, scenarios

I have a simple Cucumber feature file with a simple scenario. It looks like:

```
Feature: Admin login
  As user I want to login
  To have access to admin

  Scenario: Login in with valid credentials and open Admin page
    Given Login with valid credentials
    When Click on admin link
    Then Check admin page
```

I also have a AdminLoginSteps file that contains Java code. It looks like:

```
package steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;


public class AdminLoginSteps
{

    @Given("Login with valid credentials")
    public void loginWithValidCredentials() {
    }


    @When("Click on admin link")
    public void clickOnAdminLink() {
    }


    @Then("Check admin page")
    public void checkAdminPage() {
    }
}
```

I dont know if it is important but paths to this files are:
C:\SeleniumTests\cucumber.tatrytec.eu\src\test\features\AdminLogin.feature
C:\SeleniumTests\cucumber.tatrytec.eu\src\test\java\steps\AdminLoginSteps.java

But as I try to run the feature scenario it throws me an error:

```
Step undefined
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with it? The weird part is that I have also another feature file which is in the same directory and it works well. I don't understand what happened there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the feature file and steps files did not have the same name to link each other.